# How can I get the children (SubKeys) of a registry key?

Tags: c#

I have a key that contains a list of keys that contains user information, and now when my form loads, I want to get those keys as an array. How should I do that? I found methods for getting the counts but still don't know how to get those keys.

Comment: `RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames`? This really has nothing to do with Visual Studio, by the way... it's just the .NET registry API.

Comment: it worked! thanks for answering my question. and i know that it is .NET API, i wanted to make sure people won't be confused about what kind of registry was i talking about, should have used windows registry i guess. thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` and the `GetSubKeyNames`

```
RegistryKey MyReg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\SomeCompany\\SomeApp\\SomeVer", true);

var subKeys = MyReg.GetSubKeyNames()
```